# Finding the optimal weights in a one layer and two hidden units network

Tags: tensorflow, scikit-learn, keras, neural-network

SKlearn's neural network implementation can not consistently find the optimal weights with the best landing at acc=0.975 but not always (seemingly depending on the initailizaition) 
[image: sklearn NN with two hidden units]

How to guarantee optimal accuracy in such a simple settings?
Why the Keras version is not even getting close?

I am new to neural networks and interested in sparse models i.e. highest accuracy with least parameters. Sklearn with lbfgs solver seems sometimes to land the optimal weights

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.datasets import make_moons, make_circles, make_classification
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

X, y =make_moons(n_samples=200, noise=0.1, random_state=0)
X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.4, random_state=42)
x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - .5, X[:, 0].max() + .5
y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - .5, X[:, 1].max() + .5

#sklearn

nn=MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(2,),
                 alpha=alpha, 
                 max_iter=100000000, 
                 solver='lbfgs',
                 activation='tanh',
                 verbose=False).fit(X_train, y_train)
print(nn.score(X_test, y_test))



# Keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(2, input_dim=2, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))


model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, 
          epochs=900,
          batch_size=200,
          validation_data=(X_test, y_test), 
          verbose=0)
print(model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)[1])
```

the weights for sklearn's model where I landed the 0.975 accuracy are

```
print(nn.coefs_)
array([[-0.66491063, -5.99816399],
      [ 0.13907145, -3.82369965]]), 
array([[-16.53339218],
       [  9.14208312]])]
print(nn.intercepts_)
[array([0.04063317, 0.01169239]), array([0.40667715])]
```

Comment: Is the out of sample accuracy acc=0.975? Also, curious what the f1 score is?

Comment: @DanielScott yes the accuracy was measured on the test set. I will add the decision boundary plot

Comment: Thanks, that's great. Looks like it should be very possible for the keras model to generalize as well as the sklearn model. What accuracy are you getting on keras?

Comment: @DanielScott no more than 0.91. It is basically drawing a straight line

Comment: Ahh, so it sounds like an issue with regularization.

Comment: Can you lower the batch size to 50? You only have 200 samples (including train and test), and yet you have asked the keras model to use 200 training samples every epoch. In other words, you have told it to expect a much higher number of samples than you are providing. Very cusrious if that solves your issue @hashimov! With nn, straight lines is usually a symptom that the minimal conditions for learning haven't been reached.

Comment: @DanielScott the layers have no regularization by default. Changing the batch did not help( acc=0.88)

Comment: Can you try lowering your epochs to 100? I want to see how that changes accuracy.